# Web2py: Crud form into modal

Tags: web2py

I have a table filled with records. Every row has an Edit button.
What I am trying to do is when I click on it I want to display a modal that contains a Crud form to edit a particular record. 
On the 'Edit' button, I pass the Id of that record as an argument.

This is my try so far.

Controller

```
def Career():
    career= db(db.Career.id>0).select()
    class Virtual(object):
        def botones(self):
            bts = DIV(XML(A(SPAN(_class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'),_href=URL('Tools','careerUpdate',args=[self.Career.id]),_id="edit",_class='btn btn-default Jview btn-xs')))
            return bts
    career.setvirtualfields(campos_virtual = Virtual())
    return dict(formListar=career)


def careerUpdate():
       return dict(formCareerUpdate=crud.update(db.Career,request.args(0),message=T("Updated")))
```

View

```
<script>
    $('#edit').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 btn = $(this);
 thisHref = btn.attr('href');
 $('#myModalEdit').modal('show')
 .one('click', '#warning', function(e) {
    window.location = thisHref;});
 });

</script>


<a class="btn btn-default"  href="/{{=request.application}}/Tools/editCareer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Edit</a>


<div id="myModalEdit" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Career</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>
           {{=formCareerUpdate}}
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```